# Rails 5 & Devise: Minimum password length not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using Rails 5 & Devise and in initializers/devise.rb:

```
config.password_length = 6..128
```

registrations/new.html.erb:

```
 <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: user_registration_path, :html => {:class => "col s12 form-text", autocomplete: "off"}, validate: true) do |f| %>


          <%= f.text_field :full_name, :class => "validate", :placeholder => "Robin Smith", :required => true %>
          <%= f.email_field :email, :class => "validate", :required => true, placeholder: " " %>
          <%= f.password_field :password, :class => "validate", :required => true, placeholder: " " %>
        <%= f.submit :class => "waves-effect waves-light btn-flat", :value => "Join Now" %>
    <% end %>
```

And routes:

```
resources :users
devise_for :users, path: '', path_names: { sign_up: 'register', sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout'}
```

User.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, 
          :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable,
          :omniauthable
  validates :email, :uniqueness => true
  validates_format_of :email,:with => Devise::email_regexp
```

For some reason the user is still able to set a password of 0-5 characters.

Comment: did you restart rails server after putting the value in config?

Comment: realized I didn't have :validatable in the model .....