# Rspec ignores min length of a password specified in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

In the config of Devise I have the password min length to be 8.

```
# config/initializers/devise.rb

config.password_length = 8..128
```

However, my rspec **test passes** when a password 4 characters:

```
u = User.new({
  password: "test",
  # ....
})

expect(u).to be_valid
```

Comment: I always use shoulda for testing validations, `it { should ensure_length_of(:password).is_at_least(size_of_password) }`

Comment: have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41836736/rails-5-devise-minimum-password-length-not-working ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Testing password length validation with RSpec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13111328/testing-password-length-validation-with-rspec)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `shoulda`, can you try doing this

```
describe User do
  it "should validate the length of password" do
    FactoryGirl.build(:user, password: "aaaaa").should_not be_valid
  end
end
```

or if you want to use `shoulda`

```
it { should ensure_length_of(:password).is_at_least(8) }
```

and if you want to check for max length,

```
it { should ensure_length_of(:password).is_at_most(18) }
```

---

Comment: and if I want to use shoulda?

Comment: @Rattiku Did my solution work for you or are you facing the same issue ?